# Connect to C++ signal from QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I want to connect to C++ signals from QML like this:

```
action.onMouseUp = function() {
    console.log("mouse up>>");
}
```

And declare in my C++ object this signal:

```
signals:
  void mouseUp(const QPointF point);
```

But I'm getting QML Error: TypeError: Cannot assign to read-only property "mouseUp". What might the problem be?

Comment: But where do you call `connect`?

Comment: The assigment operator - I want to conect to signal using assignment operator

Comment: Replace the `=` by a `:` and drop the `function()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [call connect method](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-signals.html#connecting-signals-to-methods-and-signals) of action.onMouseUp object.

```js
action.onMouseUp.connect( function() {
    console.log("mouse up>>");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution:

```
Q_PROPERTY(QJSValue onMouseUp READ onMouseUp WRITE setOnMouseUp)
```

It works even without connect()

Comment: May I ask how you implement „setOnMouseUp” method?

Comment: setOnMouseUp(const QJSValue &value) { m_value = value; ) where m_value is a class member that will be called later using m_value.call();

Comment: So you bind to signal a C++ lambda that call a m_value? Or you manually call m_value whenever you emit the signal?

Comment: no, I store in m_value JavaScript lambda and call m_value instead of emitting signal

Comment: You are misusing properties, you want a signal but you expose it as property. @Arpegius is the cleanest solution. Your solution is more like with a hammer everything looks like a nail.